# Delete multiple objects in the Outliner

Tags: outliner

Is it possible to delete multiple objects in the Outliner? The way I delete objects now is by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> on them on the Outliner, then <kbd>Right Click</kbd> then selecting Delete. However, this only works on the active element, not on all selected objects.

How do I delete all the selected objects?

**EDIT:** I tried selecting the objects then pressing on <kbd>X</kbd> on the 3D Viewport to select Delete, but it doesn't seem to be working. Please see the GIF below:

[image: Blender delete not working]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can be excused for being confused as it would seem logical to click the names of the object - rather you should click further down the bar and you will see the row colour change tone. You don't even need to hold down shift to select more items. Note that selecting items this way has nothing to do with the selection in the 3D window. Once selected you can just right click and select 'delete'.

Other keys that work here - <kbd>A</kbd> toggle (select all/ deselect all) note colour tone difference. Also <kbd>B</kbd> box select, and then middle box to remove select, work here.

Once you see how it works ...it is pretty efficient.

[image]

Comment: Clicking on the name in the bar is different to clicking on the blank space at the end of the bar? I didn't realise it worked like that and that is quite confusing - especially for newbies - but I see how that works.

Comment: Oh god, I feel so dumb now. I hope I'm forgiven!

Comment: Don't feel dumb. Blender is so not intuitive when it comes to small things like this...

Answer (score 4):

Once you've selected multiple objects in the Outliner, move the mouse over the 3D window and press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete.

There are other methods of selecting multiple objects - such as holding shift and right-clicking objects in the 3D window, which has the same effect (and if you accidentally select an object you didn't want selectied you can hold shift and click the object again to de-select it). If all the objects are around the same location you could use the 'box select' tool in the 3D window - press <kbd>B</kbd>, click at the top left corner of the selection then click at the bottom right and all objectswithin that boundary will be selected (then press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete them). Also, try pressing <kbd>C</kbd> when in the 3D window - this will give you a circle and you can use this to click each area to select, once happy with the selection press right mouse button and can again press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete (or any other action you might want to do to the selected objects - rotate <kbd>R</kbd>, scale <kbd>S</kbd>, hide (<kbd>H</kbd> - use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide), etc.).

Comment: Please use <kbd> tags around keyboard keys, e.g. "press <kbd>B</kbd>"

Comment: @RayMairlot - how would I write Alt-H with this? Nothing I try looks quite right.

Comment: Not everyone does, but most put a '+' sign inbetween: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: Hm... I actually just tried this and it doesn't seem to be working? Please see the edit!

Comment: Do you have multiple scenes? Could be that the objects are not in the currently selected scene - in which case, you'd be able to select them in the outliner but not in the 3D view (as they would not be there). When you seect them in the outliner can you see the actual object get selected (and highlighted as if selected) in the 3D view?

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.8:

1. Blender Preferences > Keymap > Outliner
2. Find Delete Collection  — with Backspace
3. Change command to `object.delete`, uncheck ‘Confirm’

[image: Delete image from outliner with one keypress]

Select an object in outliner and press Backspace. Works with multiple objects selected too.